# Drawing two PMOS in 90 degree to each other

Tags: circuitikz

[image]Can anyone please help me to draw two PMOS lying 90 degree to each other as the attached figure?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The following code I wrote down before struggling with bending the PMOS direction.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
     \begin{document}
      \begin{circuitikz}
        \begin{scope}[scale=0.525]
            \draw[color=black, thin]

            %% Inverters are drawn
            (0,0)   node[pmos,xscale=-1] (pmos1) {}
            (16,0)  node[pmos] (pmos2) {}
            (8,-1)  node[pmos] (pmos3) {} to (8,-5)
            ;
        \end{scope}
\end{circuitikz}
```

\end{document}

Best regards
Saikat

Comment: What have you tried? You tag this `circuitikz`, so what prevents you from providing a small document using this package that shows what you have achieved, and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only second what Schrödinger's cat wrote in his comment.

However a mysterious element in your schematic caught my attention and i couldn't resist to implement it. Unfortunately i still don't know what the symbol depicts.

Here is an example which shows the new element in action. Coincidentally it shows the arrangement of three transistors like in your image. Just feel inspired to work on your own version.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{capacitors}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/mysterious/height}}
{mysterious}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/mysterious/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/mysterious/width}}
{
    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}

    \pgf@circ@res@step = \ctikzvalof{bipoles/mysterious/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen 
    \divide \pgf@circ@res@step by 12

    \pgf@circ@res@temp = \ctikzvalof{bipoles/mysterious/height}\pgf@circ@scaled@Rlen
    \divide \pgf@circ@res@temp by 20

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+6*\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+6*\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down+3*\pgf@circ@res@temp-0.04*\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathcircle{%
        \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+6*\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@down+3*\pgf@circ@res@temp-0.5*\pgfstartlinewidth}
    }{0.04*\pgf@circ@Rlen}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down+3*\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgfstartlinewidth+0.04*\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down+3*\pgf@circ@res@temp+\pgfstartlinewidth+0.04*\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+6*\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+6*\pgf@circ@res@step}{\pgf@circ@res@up-3*\pgf@circ@res@temp-0.04*\pgf@circ@Rlen-0.5*\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up-3*\pgf@circ@res@temp-0.04*\pgf@circ@Rlen-\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up-3*\pgf@circ@res@temp-0.04*\pgf@circ@Rlen-\pgfstartlinewidth}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    % Inner Block
    \pgfscope
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners
            {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left+\pgfstartlinewidth}{\pgf@circ@res@up-3*\pgf@circ@res@temp-0.12*\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
            {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right-\pgfstartlinewidth}{\pgf@circ@res@down+3*\pgf@circ@res@temp+0.12*\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
        \pgf@circ@draworfill
    \endpgfscope
}

\def\pgf@circ@mysterious@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{mysterious}{#1}}

\compattikzset{%
    mysterious/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@mysterious@path, l=#1}
}

\makeatother

\ctikzset{
    bipoles/mysterious/width/.initial = .25,
    bipoles/mysterious/height/.initial = 0.8
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw 
        (0,0) node[above]{$V_\text{dd}$} to[Tpmos, n=t1, o-] (0,-2) to (0,-3) to[mysterious] (0,-6) { (\tikztotarget) edge[dashed] ++(0,-0.66) }
        (6,0) node[above]{$V_\text{dd}$} to[Tpmos, n=t2, mirror, o-] (6,-2) to (6,-3) to[mysterious, mirror] (6,-6) { (\tikztotarget) edge[dashed] ++(0,-0.66) };

    \draw (t1.G) to[short]  (t2.G);

    \draw (3,0) node[above]{$\phi_\text{pre}$} to[short, o-*] (\tikztostart |- t1.G);

    \draw (0,-2) to[Tpmos, *-*] (6,-2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, +1. Although I suspect that the OP's mysterious components are just two complementary  MOS drawn (too) tightly face to face (eek).

Comment: @Rmano Thanks! Especially for the development of circuitikz! The library has become an essential part in my tikz ecosystem. Regarding the depicted schematic: maybe u are right with your interpretation. In this case the principle of operation remains obscure for me, though.

Comment: I think they are [transmission gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate) driven by complementary signals.

Comment: @Rmano interesting and thanks for answering